# Why do I keep getting a NullPointer error when I first run this app?

Tags: java, android, debugging

It was running fine before I added the swap and refresh methods.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.tilegame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener 
{
    TableLayout table;
    Button buttons[];
    int count = 0;
    int btnSize = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.box_size);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);      
        buttons = new Button[9];
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            if(x < 8)
            {
                Button btn = createButton(btnSize, false, x+1);
                buttons[x] = btn;
            }
            else if(x == 8)
            {
                Button btn = createButton(btnSize, true, x+1);
                buttons[x] = btn;
            }
        }
        randomizeArray(buttons);
        refresh();
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case 0:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 1:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 2:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 3:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 4:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 5:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 6:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 7:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;
        }
    }

    public Button createButton(int size, boolean blank, int id)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(this);

        LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(size, size);
        buttonParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        btn.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        btn.setId(id);
        btn.setText(""+btn.getId());
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(blank == false)
        {
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {
            btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return btn;
    }

    public void randomizeArray(Button[] array)
    {
        List<Button> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Button i : array)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
        {
            array[x] = list.get(x);
        }
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        table.removeAllViews();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                row.addView(buttons[count]);
                count++;
            }
            table.addView(row, x);
        }
    }

    public void swap(Button btns[], int id)
    {
        int posClick = 0;
        int posBlank = 0;
        Button temp1 = new Button(this);
        Button temp2 = new Button(this);

        for(int x = 0; x < btns.length; x++)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(btns[x].getText().toString()) == id)
            {
                posClick = x;
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < btns.length; x++)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(btns[x].getText().toString()) == 9)
            {
                posBlank = x;
            }
        }
        switch(posClick)
        {
            case 0:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 3)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 1:
                if(posBlank == 0 || posBlank == 2 || posBlank == 4)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 2:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 5)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 3:
                if(posBlank == 0 || posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 6)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 4:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 3 || posBlank == 5 || posBlank == 7)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 5:
                if(posBlank == 2 || posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 8)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 6:
                if(posBlank == 3 || posBlank == 7)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
            case 7:
                if(posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 6 || posBlank == 8)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tilegame.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#38c0f4"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_1">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_2">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_3">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_5"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_7"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_7">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_8"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_8">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/blank"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Log Cat:

```
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418): Process: com.example.tilegame, PID: 3418
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tilegame/com.example.tilegame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:94)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at com.example.tilegame.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:24)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
10-04 02:16:25.797: E/AndroidRuntime(3418):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for the help.

Also, I am used to debugging java code, but where in Log Cat does it show the line number in my Main Activity that would throw the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
int btnSize = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.box_size);
```

Do this instead:

```
private int btnSize = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Other codes here...
    btnSize = (int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.box_size);
}
```

Comment: But it was more noob friendly :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `getResourses()` method. You can't call `getResources()` before your activity class is "officially" instantiated (it's an instance method, and at that point you don't have an instance yet).

Use `getResourses()` in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: How exactly is that implemented?